# LaTeX Error with SIAM template

Tags: templates

I downloaded siamart_0516.zip from https://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php and tried to run `latex ex_article`. This gives some errors (see log below). However, `pdflatex ex_article` works just fine.

What is causing the errors with `latex`, and how can I fix it?

I'm using the standard texlive distribution on Linux Mint.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ex_article.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 4 languages loaded.
(./siamart0516.cls
Document Class: siamart0516 2016/05/27 v1.4 LaTeX document e-class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntheorem/ntheorem.sty
Style `ntheorem', Version 1.33 <2011/08/15>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/xr-hyper.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breakurl/breakurl.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hypdvips/hypdvips.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/bookmark.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/bkm-dvips.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/hypcap.sty)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Package hypdvips Options:

[ ] autoauthor
[ ] autotitle
[ ] detailedbr
[x] emptypagelabels
[ ] evenboxes
[x] fish
[ ] flip
[ ] fullbookmarks
[x] hypertnotes
[x] JavaScript�
[ ] landscape
[ ] loabr
[ ] lofbr
[ ] lotbr
[ ] Mac
[ ] mirror
[x] nlwarning
[x] openmessage
[x] quadpoints
[ ] showdests
[x] smallfootnotes
[ ] tocbr
[ ] twoside
language = english
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


! LaTeX Error: \listoffigures undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3209   \renewcommand{\listoffigures}
                                      {%
? 

! LaTeX Error: \listoftables undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3219   \renewcommand{\listoftables}
                                     {%
? 

! LaTeX Error: \tableofcontents undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3229   \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}
                                        {%
? 
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty)

! LaTeX Error: Command \listoffigures already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1584 \newcommand{\listoffigures}{}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \listoftables already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1585 \newcommand{\listoftables}{}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \tableofcontents already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1586 \newcommand{\tableofcontents}{}

? 
) (./ex_shared.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)

Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported.

)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithmic.sty))

Package xr Warning: 
No file ex_supplement.aux
LABELS NOT IMPORTED.
 on input line 23.

(./ex_article.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:proof' on page 1 undefined on input line 84.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `GoVa13' on page 1 undefined on input line 86.

[1] [2] (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:foo' on page 1 undefined on input line 181.

<lexample_fig1.eps> [3]
No file ex_article.bbl.
[4] (./ex_article.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )
Output written on ex_article.dvi (4 pages, 80796 bytes).
Transcript written on ex_article.log.
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `pdftex` instead of `pdflatex`?

Comment: @ienissei ? the Op has used latex (dvi mode) not pdflatex (the same program, in pdf mode)

Comment: I do not have that class but it appears not to define \listoffigures but the hypdvips package tries to redefine it leading to an error. do you need hypdvips here rather than standard hyperref dvips functionality?

Comment: there is a `nohypdvips` class option which looks promising (untested)

Comment: David: nohypdvips seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a current (texlive 2016) distribution there is no error but a mismatched `\ifx` somewhere causes a warning

```
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 161 was incomplete)
```

on the supplied example file, however the error shown in the question occurs in `hypdvips` package code and the `[nohypdvips]` option suppresses the loading of that package.